# Control + S deploying reports to reportserver?

Tags: ssrs-2008, reportmanager

I have experienced this one, I had try to save the rdl and it happends that it deploys all the reports in the project instead of saving it. Does anyone experienced it?How to resolved this kind of issue?

Answer (score 1):

Start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173782(v=sql.105).aspx

Ctrl-S while the focus is in the report design surface will save the RDL - I couldn't get it to do anything when I put the focus in Solution Explorer.

Are you running any sort of keystroke manager which might be trapping the hot key and sending a deploy command? I don't even think there's a shortcut key for executing deploy - I suppose a framework might deploy a macro which could automate deployment.